# Qual a diferença entre pull-based and push-based development?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos

Qual a diferença entre pull-based and push-based development na engenharia de software? Isso se refere ao Git também?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso não parece ter algo a ver com Git, pelo menos não diretamente. É usado em projetos em geral.

No ***push*** um tarefa é criada e designada para alguém adequado (em um sentido amplo) para realizá-la. Eventualmente pode demorar um pouco para designar. É considerado o jeito "tradicional".

No ***pull*** as tarefas são criadas e enfileiradas, quem estiver disponível pega a tarefa que está na prioridade da fila ou a que desejar e executa. Em geral usado em Scrum.

[Artigo](https://saintgimp.org/2010/01/21/push-vs-pull-in-scrum/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ok, até retirei a tag do git da pergunta. Obrigado!

Comment: Eu entendi a resposta. Só acho que "é considerado o jeito tradicional" no push development é uma opiniao sua que difere da minha que sempre vivenciou o Scrum no ultimos 8 anos.

Comment: É que o Scrum não é tradicional :)